# Fetch NFT listings from popular marketplaces

Tags: nft, erc-721, opensea, markets

maybe this is not the right place to ask about this, but I don't know where to ask this question. So, for suggestions on where to ask, I would also be grateful.
I have been looking for a way to fetch active NFT listings of a specified collection on the most popular marketplaces like OpenSea, Blur, Rarible, etc., but I didn't find an API to do so, except for the OpenSea API. The problem here is that it is only for OpenSea, and I read that getting an API key is difficult.

Does anybody know a good way to do so, or a website that can be easily web scraped for the same effect?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a more unified solution, you can consider using services like [QuickNode](https://www.quicknode.com) or [Covalent](https://www.covalenthq.com/) that offer APIs with aggregated data from multiple NFT marketplaces. However, these services might require API keys and might not include all marketplaces you're interested in so please do verify, they have demo call samples I believe.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find anything in the documentation of the mentioned tools regarding active listings on Marketplaces. Only that you can query basic data about collections. Could you send me a link where I can find the necessary info for my usecase?